# Extract quarters from time

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, time

Is is possible to breakdown hour into quarters and extract them?
For example:

```
7:00-7:15 = 1
7:15-7:30 = 2
etc
```

I have time column with values such as 09:30
and I want to extract:

```
hour = 6
quarter = 2
```

I can take out the hour, but how do I take out the quarter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`datepart` function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
select 
    case 
        when TimeColumn is null then null
        when datepart(minute, TimeColumn) < 15 then 1
        when datepart(minute, TimeColumn) < 30 then 2
        when datepart(minute, TimeColumn) < 45 then 3
        else 4
    end
from MyTable
```